# Ruby on rails relationship reference saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm just wondering what is the best practice in saving this kind of data

Here's the relationship of the models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :user
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many   :reviews
end
```

Currently I'm saving them in this kind of code

```
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = current_user.reviews.build(comment_param)
    @comment.post_id = params[:post_id]
    if @comment.save
        flash[:success] = 'Successfully created a comment'
        @post
    else
        flash[:error] = 'Error'
        @post
    end
end
```

Here's the form opening tag.

```
form_for([@post,@post.comment.build]) do |f|
    %p
       = f.label :title, class: 'control-label'
       = f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control'
    %p
       = f.label :message, class: 'control-label'
       = f.text_area :message, class: 'form-control'
```

How can i shortcut it so that i will not assign the post_id manually and let the rails parse it

Comment: Please clarify your relation that are bit confusing someone to get your problem.

Comment: Hi Bharat soni I think the relationship is not so complicated enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
@comment = current_user.comments.build(comment_param.merge(:post_id => params[:post_id]))
```

or

```
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@comment = @post.comments.build(comment_param.merge(:user => current_user))
```

**Update:**

Or you can add a `scope` to your `Comment` model:

```
# in comment.rb
scope :by_user, ->(user) { where(:user_id => user.id) }

# and then in the controller
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@comment = @post.comments.by_user(current_user).build(comment_param)
```

Comment: @PrettyOdd: I updated my answer and would suggest to go with the third option.